# mySQL put results with same id in same column

Tags: mysql, sql, json, api, select

I am working on an app that is connected with MySQL database.

I have a problem with showing data.

This is my select in database

```
SELECT
  a_activity.id,
  team.name,
  b_activity.team_id,
  a_activity.number
FROM a_activity,
     team,
     b_activity
WHERE team.id = b_activity.team_id
AND b_activity.id = a_activity.team_activity_id;
```

This is my results on API link

```
{
"statistic": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test A",
        "team_id": 1,
        "number": "103,122"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 18",
        "team_id": 2,
        "number": "113,132"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Test 15",
        "team_id": 3,
        "number": "133,129"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Test 10",
        "team_id": 4,
        "number": "113,112"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "team_name": "Test A",
        "team_id": 1,
        "number": "123,152"
    }
]
}
```

But I want to put result (number) in the same row in JSON or in the database in the same column. I want to my JSON be something like this example under the post.

```
{
"statistic": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test A",
        "team_id": 1,
        "number": "103,122, 123,152"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 18",
        "team_id": 2,
        "number": "113,132"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Test 15",
        "team_id": 3,
        "number": "133,129"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Test 10",
        "team_id": 4,
        "number": "113,112"
    }
]
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Learn about rearranging arrays. I found it an incredibly difficult task to master (I still struggle), but pays dividends

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem , here is answer

```
SELECT b_activity.team_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (a_activity.number)) AS 
number
FROM a_activity
INNER JOIN b_activity
ON a_activity.team_activity_id = b_activity.id
GROUP BY b_activity.team_id
```